# Find a range and then clear contents from another range based upon the found range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Not sure if i've explained this very well in my question but I will try to explain better here.

What I would like to do is understand how I can search a range for specific text and use that search to define a range that I can clear contents from. the area I want to clear contents from has some fixed data in there that I would want to skip clearing. But the data I want to clear is always on a fixed range of cells.

To explain better. If I have a search range of A2:G50, I want to search that range for data, based upon a drop down list.  Once found I then want to clear contents in range A for 11 cells then C:G for 11 cells. leaving the contents in range B.

Any help in what that VBA would look like would be much appreciated, as I have no idea.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim rgFound As Range
Set rgFound = Sheets("Planning").Range("A:A").Find(What:="AD6")

Range("rgFound").Resize(11, 12).Offset(, 2).Clear


End Sub
```

Getting Aplication /object defined runtime error 1004

Thank you

Comment: What exactly have you tried and where did you get stuck or errors? Please note that because this is no free code writing service, so we can only help you if you show your code and ask a question to it. Have a look at the official documentation of the methods `Find`, `Offset` and `Resize` which would help you to solve your issue or to try something on your own if you haven't yet.

Comment: Apologies,I really am sub-amateur at this. I have some code that I cant quite get to work that will do part of it.

Comment: OP updated. Sorry, i'm trying to juggle a number of tasks due to business critical Covid responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Range("rgFound")` it is just `rgFound`. This variable is a reference to the found range.

Note that you must check if something was found at all before using it:

```
If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then
    'now you can use rgFound
    rgFound.Resize(11, 12).Offset(, 2).Clear
Else
    MsgBox "nothing was found"
End If
```

Also note that for the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) you need also define the `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder` and `MatchByte` parameters. Otherwise Excel will use whatever was used before in the user interface or by VBA (and your find will randomly work or not). So you should explicitly define them.

Comment: Thank you, I got that working. It is very much appreciated.